# Connect to Postgres using Python psycopg2 and LDAP user

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have this information

```
jdbc:postgresql://<host>:5432/<database>?ApplicationName=SPARK_PERFORMANCE_TESTING 

PostgresUserName = <user> 

PostgresPassword = <password>
```

I am doing some REST API development. Some APIs have to extract information from postgresSql.How to use this info to build LDAP URI or How to use it with Psycopg2 ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the LDAP part... but do you just want to get data from a postgresql database with a python script?

Comment: Naah..I want to connect to remote Postgres server using LDAP user.

Comment: can you try first authenticate the user against a LDAP server and then get the data? But to access it's okay to use the same postgres user for all actions?